# Asymptotic behavior at $0$ of concave function

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Let $\varphi(t)$ be a (strictly) increasing concave function with $\varphi(0)=0$, and $B>1$. It´s easy to see that
\begin{equation}
 1 \le \liminf_{ t\to 0^+} \frac{\varphi(Bt)}{\varphi(t)} \le B.
\end{equation}
We are looking for an example that fullfill the hypotesys and where the limit is exactly $1$.

This type of limits appears, for example, to determine whether the Orlicz space of sequences $\ell_{\varphi}$ is locally bounded or not (the answer is yes, iff the limit is greater than $1$ for some constant $B>1$).

Our original setup is taking $\varphi(t)=\int_0^t \phi$, where $\phi$ is positive and decreasing (non-increasing), integrable in $(0,\alpha)$ for some $\alpha >0$. In this context, if $\phi$ is bounded then the limit is always $B$. So, we have to look an unbounded functión. Taking $\phi(t)=t^{-r}, 0<r<1$, the limit is greater than 1. For $r=1$ the limit is (would be, using L´Hospital rule) $1$, but $\varphi$ is no longer defined, as the function $1/t$ is not integrale in $0$.

Is there an example where de limit is exactly $1$? Futher, is there a way to characterize the class of functions $\varphi$ for which the limit is $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
\varphi(t) = \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{ if } t = 0 \, ,\\
 -1/\ln(t) & \text{ if } 0 < t < e^{-2} \, .
\end{cases}
$$
It can be verified easily that $\varphi $ is strictly increasing and stricly concave on $[0, e^{-2}]$. For every $B > 1$ is
$$
 \lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{\varphi(Bt)}{\varphi(t)} =  \lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{\ln(t)}{\ln(t) + \ln(B)} = 1 \, .
$$

(If necessary, $\varphi$ can be extended to an increasing concave function on $[0, \infty)$, this does not affect the limit of the quotient at $t = 0$.)

*Remark:* For a concave increasing function $\varphi$ with $\varphi(0) = 0$ is $\varphi(t)/t$ decreasing, so that the limit
$$
 \lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{\varphi(t)}{t}
$$
exists, but can be $+\infty$. If that limit is *finite* then
$$
\lim_{t \to 0^+}\frac{\varphi(Bt)}{\varphi(t)} = B
$$
follows, therefore the idea was to look for functions with a vertical asymptote at the origin.

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed!. Following your example, it was easy to check that $\varphi(t)=\frac{1}{p-1} (-\ln(t))^{1-p}$, with $p>1$ and $t \in (0,e^{-p})$ would do the job. Regarding your remark, and following the notation I used in the question, that's (I think) the case when $\phi$ is bounded. On the other hand, I was not yet able to find a general characterization of the class of functions $\varphi$ for which the limit is $1$. Or even an example where the limit does not exist but the liminf is $1$.